# Treeview remember IsExpanded when refreshing

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, treeview

I am creating a WPF TreeView which binds to an XML file (or the other way around .. ) using this XAML code

```
<UserControl x:Class="XmlOutline.OutlineWindowControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:vsshell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.15.0"
             Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowKey}}"
             Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsshell:VsBrushes.WindowTextKey}}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="MyToolWindow">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="XmlProvider" Source="LogansTest.xml" XPath="/Items"/>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="NodeTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./*}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="nodetext"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NodeType}" Value="Element">
                    <Setter TargetName="nodetext" Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.Triggers>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>


    <Grid x:Name="TreeGrid" DataContext="XmlProvider">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TreeView Name="TreeItems"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NodeTemplate}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And I'm setting the Xml context like this

```
var provider = new XmlDataProvider()
{
Source = new Uri(gotFocus.Document.Path + gotFocus.Document.Name), XPath = "./*"
};

OutlineWindowInstance.TreeItems.DataContext = provider;
```

When I then edit the Xml file and save the changes I call

```
var prov = (XmlDataProvider) OutlineWindowInstance.TreeItems.DataContext;
prov.Refresh();
```

This Updates the treeview which is great, but it also contracts all nodes rather than remembering the IsExpanded state.
I can't figure out how to make it remember the state, can anyone point me in the right direction? :)

Comment: What I like doing in these cases is to create a MyTreeViewNode class that inherits the standard TreeViewNode class.  Then add a property like Boolean expanded { get; set;}.  Then after updating your TreeView you can parse the tree and restore to previous state.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean when you say Parse, could you give me a code example? :)

Comment: I probably should of said Transverse the Tree.

Comment: It sounds like it's something that there would be a feature for though, also I tried doing it that way a few a few days ago, but I have some documents that are 9000 lines of xml or more, and it becomes unbearably heavy.
It does strike me though that I checked all nodes, regardless of whether their parents were closed or not, I could likely waste a lot less energy by traversing only as far as it's open.

Comment: Then make a list of open nodes so you don't have to search all 9000 lines.  Every time I work with a Treeview that uses an xml I keeping on saying I should line Each TreeNode to the associated Xml Element, but never have done this.

Comment: I still haven't fixed this .. xD
I have created a list of objects to save the nodes that are expanded.
But I'm not sure how to get at the actual treeviewitem and set it to expanded, I get the data from
"void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)"

But I can't figure out how to get the actual treeviewitem when I refresh the tree data, i tried
(TreeViewItem)e.OriginalSource, but it losses binding on refresh

Comment: By the way I've put it up on Github if you'd like to use it yourself, I really want this "remember expansion state" to work before creating a new release though, the old one is fairly slow as it's before I did databinding :)

https://github.com/LoganLabster/VsXmlOutline

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
       public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            TreeNode newNode1 = new TreeNode("Node 1");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode1);

            TreeNode newNode1a = new TreeNode("Node 1a");
            newNode1.Nodes.Add(newNode1a);
            treeView1.Click += new EventHandler(treeView1_Click);


            TreeNode newNode2 = new TreeNode("Node 2");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode2);


            TreeNode newNode3 = new TreeNode("Node 3");
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode3);



        }
        void treeView1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeView  node = sender as TreeView;
            if (node != null)
            {
                TreeNode selectedNode = node.SelectedNode;
                string nodeName = selectedNode.Name;
                Boolean expanded = selectedNode.IsExpanded;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is this Windows Forms? 
It doesn't really look like Windows Presentation Foundation (from my admittedly limited experience)

Comment: I tested with a Form not WPF. Adding event should be very similar for a WPF.

Comment: I have
private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
and
private void TreeViewItem_Collapsed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

The main problem I have in setting them manually right now is that I can't find a defining feature (ID or otherwise) that is the same before and after a refresh on the tree items.
It seems the tree deletes all nodes and creates new ones on every refresh cause references to the actual TreeViewItems breaks.
I tried with the XPath of the xml document too, but I can't traverse the tree with XPath either (from what I can see)